# Change class base on value of model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
items = {'apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'tom', 'john', 'baby'}
```

html

```
 <div class="variable" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} </div>
```

What I want to do is:

variable is `fruit` when item is `apple, banana, lemon`.

variable is `animal` when item is `cat, dog, monkey`.

variable is `human` when item is `tom, john, baby`

fruit, animal, human is css class

Please help, thanks

Comment: `<div class="{{item}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your items which is uncorrect array format

```
items = {'apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'tom', 'john', 'baby'}
```

to

```
items = ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'tom', 'john', 'baby']
```

### use `ng-class` is a good approach.

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item it items" ng-class="defineClass(item)">{{item}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.items = ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'tom', 'john', 'baby'];

$scope.defineClass = function(item) {
    switch (item) {
        case 'apple':
        case 'banana':
        case 'lemon':
            return 'fruit'; 
            break;
        case 'cat':
        case 'dog':
        case 'monkey':
            return 'animal'; 
            break;
        case 'tom':
        case 'john':
        case 'baby':
            return 'human'; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class.

```
<div ng-class="{'classname':variable}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} </div>
```

For example

```
<div ng-class="{'human':item == 'tom'}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

controller

```
$scope.fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon'];
$scope.animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'monkey'];
$scope.human = ['tom', 'john', 'baby'];

$scope.items = $scope.fruit.concat($scope.animal).concat($scope.human);

$scope.is = function(type, item) {
    return ($scope[type].indexOf(item) != -1);
}
```

template

```
<div ng-class="{fruit: is('fruit',item), animal: is('animal',item), human: is('human',item)}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most scalable approach would be to use different data structure. For example:

```
var items = [
    {name: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},    
    {name: 'bannana', type: 'fruit'},
    {name: 'lemon', type: 'fruit'},
    {name: 'cat', type: 'animal'},
    {name: 'dog', type: 'animal'},
    {name: 'monkey', type: 'animal'},
    {name: 'tom', type: 'human'},
    {name: 'john', type: 'human'},
    {name: 'baby', type: 'human'}
];
```

Yes, it's more verbose, but it pays back with convenience. If tomorrow you add new item, you don't have to touch template at all or change controller code to support it. It will automatically get proper class name.

```
<div class="{{item.type}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nrlSChOkp0rC7KRPI3FO?p=preview